# Coded value domains are not showing in pop-up in JavaScript API webapp

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, domains

I have a web app that was built with JavaScript API 4.10. One of my layers is a map image layer that includes many sub-layers with some fields that have domains. The issue is that in the pop-up only the domain codes show, but not the values. If I add the map service in AGOL or Portal the domains values show correctly.

Here is the code where this specific map image layer was added:

```
var Utilities = new MapImageLayer({
url: "https://domain.../arcgis/rest/services/.../Utilities/MapServer",
title: "Utilities - CADD Master Files"
});
Utilities.watch("loaded", function() {
    for (i=0;i<Utilities.allSublayers.length;i++) {
        var this_layer = Utilities.allSublayers.items[i];
        //this_layer.visible = false;
        if (this_layer.sublayers == null) {
          crtPopUpTemplate(Utilities.url, this_layer.id,this_layer);
        }
        else {
            //console.log("This layer has a sublayer");
            //In production mode, remove console.logs 
        }
    }
  })
```

Code for the pop-up template function (used for almost all layers in the app):

```
function crtPopUpTemplate(basicURL, layerID, layerVName) {
    var url = basicURL+'/'+layerID.toString()+'?f=json';
    esriRequest(url, {responseType: "json"}).
      then(function(response){
        Alldata = response.data;
        var titleLayer = Alldata.name;
        if (titleLayer.includes('_') == true) {
            resultIf = titleLayer.replace(/_/g," ");
        } else {
          resultIf = titleLayer;
        }

        let fieldInfosArray = [];
        for(let i=0; i<Alldata.fields.length; i++) {
          fieldInfosArray[i] = {fieldName: Alldata.fields[i].name, label: Alldata.fields[i].alias}
        }

        template1 = {
        title: resultIf,
        content: [{
         type: "fields",
         fieldInfos: fieldInfosArray
        }]
        };
        layerVName.popupTemplate=template1;
      });
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this was a bug with ArcGIS JavaScript API and it was fixed with the release of JS API 4.15.

I just changed my app to use 4.15.